# How to have Running Count Items Within a Start and End Date in Amazon Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have data like this brought into a SPICE from Redshift:

```
BadgeAward StartDate EndDate
Bronze     1/15/2017 1/15/2020
Silver     2/15/2019 2/15/2020
Gold       3/15/2017  3/15/2020
Gold       3/15/2017  3/15/2020

I am putting a line graph to show at a point in time (StartDate), how many are active
At 1/15/2017, Total Badges = 1   (Only Bronze is active)
At 2/15/2019, Total Badges = 4   (Gold,Bronze and Silver are still active)
At 3/15/2017, Total Badges = 3   (Gold and Bronze are active, Silver has not started yet)
```

I have been playing around with RunningCount but cannot seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your data set and what I thought would work with a runningcount formula. As you pointed out, it doesn't seem to work. QuickSight appears to be applying a distinct_Count logic as a part of the runningcount formula instead of a pure count.

To get around the issue I create a separate calculated field in which I assigned a value of 1 to assign a 1 to every row in the data. Then I did a runningsum formula based off that field to get your desired output.

```
BadgeCount = runningsum(sum(1),[STartDate ASC],[])
```

[image]

[image]